# how to debug container images using openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, fedora

Let's say I have a docker image created using a Dockerfile. At the time of writing the Dockerfile I had to test it repeatedly to realize what I did wrong. To debug a docker image I can simply run a test container and look at its stdout/stderr to see what's wrong with the image.

```
IMAGE_NAME=authoritative-dns-bind
IMAGE_OPTIONS="
    -v $(pwd)/config.yaml:/config.yaml:ro
    -p 127.0.0.1:53:53
    -p 127.0.0.1:53:53/udp"

docker run -t -i $IMAGE_OPTIONS $IMAGE_NAME
```

Learning the above was good enough to iteratively create and debug a minimal working Docker container. Now I'm looking for a way to do the same for OpenShift.

I'm pretty much aware of the fact that the container is not ready for OpenShift. My plan is to run it and watch its stdoud/stderr like I did with Docker. One of the people I asked for help came up with a command that looked like exactly what I need.

```
oc run -i -t --image $IMAGE_NAME --command test-pod -- bash
```

And the above command seemed for me for `fedora:24` and `fedora:latest` images from the docker registry and I got a working shell. But the same wouldn't happen for my derived image with a containerized service. My explanation is that it probably does an entirely different thing and instead of starting the command interactively it starts it non-interactively and then tries to run `bash` inside a failed container.

So what I'm looking for is a reasonable way to debug a container image in OpenShift. I expected that I would be able to at least capture and view stdin/stdout of OpenShift containers.

Any ideas?

**Update**

According to the comment by Graham `oc run` should indeed work as `docker run` but it doesn't seem to be the case. With original Fedora images the bash always appears at least upon hitting enter.

```
# oc run -i -t --image authoritative-dns-bind --command test-auth13 -- bash
Waiting for pod myproject/test-auth13-1-lyng3 to be running, status is Pending, pod ready: false
Waiting for pod myproject/test-auth13-1-lyng3 to be running, status is Pending, pod ready: false
Waiting for pod myproject/test-auth13-1-lyng3 to be running, status is Pending, pod ready: false
...
Waiting for pod myproject/test-auth13-1-lyng3 to be running, status is Pending, pod ready: false    
^C
#
```

I wasn't able to try out the suggested `oc debug` yet as it seems to require more configuration than just simple image. There's another problem with `oc run` as that command creates new and new containers that I don't really need. I hope there is a way to start the debug easily and get the container automatically distroyed afterwards.

Comment: When you say it "wouldn't happen for my derived image with a containerized service", what were you actually seeing? When using ``oc run`` with a command, it shouldn't start anything up and should just run the command you give it. So nothing could have failed already. Also, if you have got as far as trying to deploy the application the image contains, you can also use ``oc debug dc mydcname``. That will start up the container with same configuration as real application gets, except is attached to terminal session and a shell run instead of your application.

Answer (score 3):

There are three main commands to debug pods:

1. `oc describe pod $pod-name` -- detailed info about the pod
2. `oc logs $pod-name` -- stdout and stderr of the pod
3. `oc exec -ti $pod-name -- bash` -- get a shell in running pod

To your specific problem: `oc run` default pull policy is set to `Always`. This means that OpenShift will try to pull the image until successful and refuse to use the local one.

Once [this kuberenetes patch](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/30614) lands in OpenShift origin, the pull policy will be easily configurable.

Comment: to get a shell you can also use `oc rsh $pod-name`

Comment: The `oc logs` command returns `Unrecognized input header` (without newline character). This doesn't look like an expected result.

Comment: @fer.marino That doesn't help if the container doesn't work which will be quite common during first experiments just as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not consider this a final answer to the question and supersede it with your own better answers...

I'm now using a pod configuration file like the following...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "authoritative-dns-server"  # pod name, your reference from command line
  namespace: "myproject"  # default namespace in `oc cluster up`
spec:
  containers:
    - command:
        - "bash"
      image: "authoritative-dns-bind"  # use your image!
      name: "authoritative-dns-bind-container"  # required
      imagePullPolicy: "Never"  # important! you want openshift to use your local image
      stdin: true
      tty: true
  restartPolicy: "Never"
```

Note the command is explicitly set to `bash`. You can then create the pod, attach to the container and run the docker command yourself.

```
oc create -f pod.yaml
oc attach -t -i authoritative-dns-server
/files/run-bind.py
```

This looks far from ideal and it doesn't really help you debug an ordinary openshift container with standard pod configuration, but at least it's possible to debug, now. Looking forward to better answers.